# Plotly: How to add elements to hover_data using plotly.express piechart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am playing with examples from plotly.express [piechart help page](https://plot.ly/python/pie-charts/) and trying to add an extra element `iso_num` to the hover_data property (`iso_num` is an int64 column in the gapminder dataframe)

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007").query("continent == 'Americas'")
fig = px.pie(df, values='pop', names='country',
             title='Population of American continent',
             hover_data=['lifeExp','iso_num'], labels={'lifeExp':'life expectancy','iso_num':'iso num'
                                                      })
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label')
fig.show()
```

Hovering over the slice of the pie chart then gives this:

[image]

where `iso num` value is `%{customdata[1]}` instead of the numeric value from the column.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a [relic](https://community.plot.ly/t/customdata-for-pie-chart-is-undefined/6021) from back when it was stated [that](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2048)

> Oh pie hover is a big mess

Which since seems to be have been [resolved](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/2117). But perhaps not for `px.pie()`?
I've tried numerous approaches, but I'm only able to get the [customdata + hovertemplate](https://plot.ly/python/hover-text-and-formatting/) approach to work for `go.Pie` and not for `px.Pie`. Here's a demonstration on how assigning values to `customdata` will make any variable otherwise *not* assigned to `go.Pie()` available for a custom hovertamplate:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007").query("continent == 'Americas'")

fig = go.Figure(go.Pie(
    name = "",
    values = df['pop'],
    labels = df['country'],
    customdata=df['iso_num'],
    hovertemplate = "Country:%{label}: <br>Population: %{value} </br> iso num:%{customdata}"

))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  Indeed, when i copy your solution into a jupyter notebook, the popup window shows the fields expected.  I haven't been precise enough in my original question: i need this piechart in a Dash application.  Now i need to figure out how to successfully use `go.Pie` instead of plotly.express in Dash.  Thanks!

Comment: @ambushed I see. I think that should work fine though.

Comment: This just seems to be a bug we can fix :)

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to do it with Plotly Express Pie chart as well. You can use `update_traces` to define `hover_template`. It seems there is an issue with splitting on multiple values for `hover_data`/`custom_data` and all values are present at 0 index only i.e. both values are at `customdata[0]`.

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007").query("continent == 'Americas'")
fig = px.pie(df, values='pop', names='country',
             title='Population of American continent',
             custom_data=['lifeExp','iso_num'], labels={'lifeExp':'life expectancy','iso_num':'iso num'
                                                      })
fig.update_traces(textposition='inside', textinfo='percent+label',\
                 hovertemplate = "Country:%{label}: <br>Population: %{value} </br>(life expentancy, iso num) : %{customdata}"
)

fig.show()
```

On hover:

[image]

Comment: You were really close. Even though customdata[0] holds both values you can access each with customdata[0][0] and customdata[0][1]